# Error : Authentication options didn't match existing session token and not interactive session so unable to manually reauthenticate

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-analytics, shiny, rstudio, shinydashboard

I'm working on an app that connects to the google API using the packages "googleAnalyticsR" and "RGA". The app works perfectly on my desktop, but when trying to deploy it in my local server I get the following error:

```
Error : Authentication options didn't match existing session token and not interactive session
           so unable to manually reauthenticate
Warning: Error in error_check: Authentication options didn't match existing session token and not intera
ctive session
           so unable to manually reauthenticate
  59: stop
  58: error_check
  57: fetch_google_analytics_4
  56: google_analytics
  52: server [/opt/shiny-server/apps/Aplicativo_Google_Analytics/server.R#20]
Error in error_check(out) :
  Authentication options didn't match existing session token and not interactive session
           so unable to manually reauthenticate
```

I already tried using this (which works on my desktop):

```
ga_auth(".httr-oauth") #For Google_analytics
token<-readRDS(".ga-token.rds") #Token for Get real time
```

How can I correct this error???

Martín

Answer (score 0):

That error is when the authentication token is not present for the script.  You need to upload the authentication file on your local machine to the server as well, and point to its file location in the `ga_auth()` function.

However, in general for server's its recommend to use service email authentication instead.